# Dealing with floating point inaccuracy

Tags: c#, regex

With regex I created a program that solves mathematical expressions. It works perfectly fine, except for expressions such as these: `(123.45*(678.90 / (-2.5+ 11.5)-(((80 -(19))) *33.25)) / 20) - (123.45*(678.90 / (-2.5+ 11.5)-(((80 -(19))) *33.25)) / 20) + (13 - 2)/ -(-11)"`.

My program solves the problem in the following steps: [image]

The result should be exactly **1** but is slightly larger. My program loops until there is one single number in the correct format. I guess I can rewrite the regex so it accepts numbers in scientific format, but still, this would return the wrong answer. How do I deal with this?
My program uses following line:

```
while (!Regex.IsMatch(expression, @"\A([+-]?[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?)\Z"))
```

Comment: FP math on a computer is prone to rounding errors. You'd normally define a small number (conventionally called Epsilon) which is your tolerance for error and call anything which differs by less than this as a match.

Comment: What exactly is the required behavior? If you want something that doesn't have floating point math behavior, you will have to use something other than floating point numbers. For example, a class with `int numerator` and `int denominator` representing arbitrary decimals, or a fixed-precision decimal class...

Comment: Brennah Vincent: Very interesting approach, I would have to rewrite the whole program to make this work.
Steve Todd: Epsilon concept sounds good, I'll give it a shot

Comment: Check out ["Is this a good way to compare two numbers?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180309/is-this-a-good-way-to-compare-two-numbers) and the code snippets from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.equals?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Double_Equals_System_Double_)

Comment: You can do this on a piece of paper and you'll have the exact same problem.  The paper won't be big enough to write all the digits in 1952.81666...  You have to stop somewhere and that will affect the result.  Computers likewise don't have infinite storage for numbers.  Nothing to do with regex or epsilon, simply a fundamental limitation in calculation.  Google "c# arbitrary precision math library" to find the kind of code that the Windows calculator applet uses.

Comment: **Do not use floats or decimals if you need accurate results for arbitrary rationals**.  Use an arbitrary-precision rational library.

Comment: Looking over all the comments here, and then at your screenshot, I can't help but wonder if your results are a bit more inaccurate. You say the result should be 1, but is slightly larger? Actually, the way I read it, it is a lot closer to zero. If we dispense with all the fractional digits but keep *all other important parts* we end up with `1e-07`, which is the same as `0.0000001`, which is much closer to 0 than it is to 1. Can you clarify?

Comment: This is also evident from the last step in your calculation where you add `-12053` and `+12053` (again, dispensing of the almost identical fractional digits). Your answer should be close to 0, not 1.

Comment: You are correct, there was an error in the program that isn't apparent in the code snippet I provided (In a case where the plus sign stands in front of expression that's being calculated). In the end, the inaccuracy is still there, I solved it with using decimals and Epsilon concept. However, I'll rewrite the program completely and try suggestions provided here to get exact results. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should just switch to Decimals instead of using floating points since, by definition, [floating point numbers accurately represent only fractions that have a power of 2 in the denominator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) while Decimals don't have this specific problem.

Comment: Haven't solved the issue entirely, but works for the particular situation.

Comment: The notion that floating point numbers are inaccurate "to save memory" does not really capture the problem. After all, if we divide a decimal 1.0 by 3 and then multiply that by 3, that's also inaccurate. A better explanation is: floating point numbers accurately represent only fractions that have a power of 2 in the denominator, and decimals accurately represent only fractions that have a power of 10 in the denominator.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks. I was trying to figure out a way to explain it without going too much into details. This is a lot more accurate, I have edited my answer.